# How to set innodb_thread_concurrency in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, concurrency, innodb

My MYSQL DB is very slow but when I change the innodb_thread_concurrency value from the default 33 to 0 selects per second rise from 30-40 to 600-700. I would like to set this value every time the DB starts. I usually change variables in my.ini. There are 3 my.ini files on my system but the one in use (listed in MYSQL Workbench) is in the programdata directory. I have tried adding the variable to all 3 but it makes no difference. I must be getting the syntax wrong but I've tried several variations:
    innodb_thread_concurrency=0
    set-variable=innodb_thread_concurrency=0
Neither seem to work. Whenever I look at the system variable (in MYSQL Workbench) the innodb_thread_concurrency is 33 until I start a session and enter : 
    set global innodb_thread_concurrency=0;
On Unix systems they talk about my.cnf but no such file exists on my W10 system.

What do I need to do to have this variable correctly set at startup?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
```

Make sure you add it to the `[mysqld]` section of the file.

Comment: @neilbarton    Ensure there is ONLY ONE innodb_thread_concurrency line in your my.ini [mysqld] section.  Last one through in the section will be used by startup.

Comment: Please post last 100 lines of TEXT from your MySQL Error Log for analysis after editing, stop/start of instance.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the `my.ini` file may be in several locations. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

```
%WINDIR%\my.ini, %WINDIR%\my.cnf
C:\my.ini, C:\my.cnf
BASEDIR\my.ini, BASEDIR\my.cnf
```

`BASEDIR` represents the MySQL base installation directory. When MySQL 8.0 has been installed using MySQL Installer, this is typically `C:\PROGRAMDIR\MySQL\MySQL 8.0 Server` where `PROGRAMDIR` represents the programs directory (usually `Program Files` on English-language versions of Windows)

The doc also says:

> On Windows, MySQL programs read startup options from the files shown in the following table, in the specified order (files listed first are read first, files read later take precedence).

This means if you have an option file in multiple locations, MySQL Server will read all of them, in the order I listed them. If a subsequent file contains a setting for `innodb_thread_concurrency`, the value it sets will replace a value set in an earlier file. Just as a line setting that value lower within one file replaces a value set earlier in the file.

So make sure you check all files thoroughly, to make sure your change in the option file isn't superseded by a later line!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wilson Hauck, it was such a bizarre default (only for Solaris systems I believe) it never occurred to me to look but there was another entry much further down the file setting it to 33! Removed that and all working as expected.